# Desktop Manager doesn't start with xorg

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gnome3, xterm

I've just installed Arch and I have installed gnome, but when I type `startx` I have the following problem

```
   waiting for X server to shut down Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.c: xterm: not found /etc/x11/xinit/xinitrc: line 55: xterm: command not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: Install xterm...  Or if you want to start gnome, create a `~/.xinitrc` as per the [Gnome Wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gnome#Starting_GNOME).

Comment: I did but always the same error

Comment: `man startx` ... You should understand how to tools you're using work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have created a `~/.xinitrc` then there's no way that `startx` should be pointing to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` since this is the **system-wide** file.

All `.xinitrc` basically is, is a shell script which starts desired clients according to the user's preference. The clients placed in this file will all be ran in the background.

Make sure that you've actually put the `.` in front of the `.xinitrc` file and it is in fact in `$HOME`. If you forgot the `.` then the file will be viewable from simply performing `ls $HOME` the `.` symbolizes a **hidden file** then you would need `ls -a $HOME` to view the file.

But, I can assure you there is **no way** the file is created and in the correct location if `startx` is pointing to the global file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a proper X session configured, `xterm` would be called, but your arch installation doesn't have that, so it would simply fail here. (Try `pacman -S extra/xterm`)

And for the gnome part, you don't have gnome installed (Try `pacman -S gnome`) or your xinitrc doesn't contain the line to launch gnome when X starts.

Put a line like this into your `~/.xinitrc`, and see if gnome launches,

`dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session`

After that, launch `startx` again.