# Nvidia Optimus laptop: startX and xinit don't work (Arch)

Tags: xorg, nvidia, x-server, startx, optimus

I can't boot my pc because the Xserver doesn't start. What's weird is that when I use SDDM it boots just fine. I also tried to use Lightdm a few months ago but it didn't want to boot, I'm guessing because of this problem.

I've had this problem for like a year but it never really bothered me because I always used SDDM. I'd like to stop using it so that's why I need this fixed.

**System Info**

Neofetch:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Host: 80WK Lenovo Y520-15IKBN 
Kernel: 4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH 
Uptime: 10 mins 
Packages: 1554 (pacman) 
Shell: zsh 5.6.2 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Breezemite 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], X-Arc-Plus [GTK3] 
Icons: Papirus-Light [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], Papirus [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: DejaVu Sans Mono 10 
CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: Intel Device 591b 
Memory: 1758MiB / 7851MiB
```

I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver. Not bumblebee or nouveau because of their performance hit.

`uname -a` : Linux ArchLinux 4.18.14-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 13 13:42:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`pacman -Q nvidia` : 
nvidia 410.57-6

I enabled [KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting) to eliminate screen tearing, but disabling it doesn't help. I don't have an xorg.conf file because when I do, even SDDM won't start. `nvidia-xconfig` has never worked for me.

**Logs:**

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

These are both executed with SDDM disabled, so I just log in to the first tty:

when executing `startx`: https://hastebin.com/zadepawiwo

when executing `xinit` : https://hastebin.com/muredinume

With SDDM enabled, so a normal boot: https://hastebin.com/anatocavur

*(is hastebin the right place or should I upload them elsewhere?)*

---

EDIT: this is what I see in the terminal when I execute:

`sudo startx`: [image: sudo startx] (That d-bus thing might be interesting but I have no idea what it means).

`startx`: [image: startx]

Here's my .xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --above eDP-1
xrandr --dpi 96


# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs


if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

sxhkd &
statnot &
feh --bg-fill ~/Pictures/DnA7hZgU8AAxfxC.jpg:large.jpg
exec bspwm
```

---

As for the 'possible duplicate' from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67601/desktop-manager-doesnt-start-with-xorg), I tried their solutions and they didn't work. For me, SDDM can start when I have it enabled, but I want to use bspwm without a DM.

---

Disabling the NVIDIA GPU in my BIOS settings made `startx` work, so that reveals that the problem is with NVIDIA. Are my drivers the problem? Is it something else?

Comment: A downvote? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have `startx` or `xinit` ever worked for you?  What is in your `.xinitrc` ?

Comment: The downvote might have been for using pastebin (or similar) -- it's better to include all the relevant text in the question: [Policy on pastebins for additional info?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/policy-on-pastebins-for-additional-info).  Same for links to external image hosts -- images can be included in the question, but should only be used when their content can't be represented in text.

Comment: The "dbus thing" suggests you have no `.xinitrc`, so the default one, `/etc/X11/xinitrc`, is being used instead.  Is `xterm` installed?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I don't think they ever worked, but I've always used SDDM so I have no clue. I edited my `.xinitrc` in the post. As for the pastebins, I can't really post the whole logs here because they are too big. Why would it not find my `.xinitrc`? Does it need special permissions? `xterm` is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop Manager doesn't start with xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67601/desktop-manager-doesnt-start-with-xorg)

Comment: Is there anything in `.xsession.errors`?

Comment: I can't find that file in my ~/ directory, is it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, if it exists it should be in your home directory.  How about `.xsession-errors`?

Comment: No, the only files that start with an 'x' are .Xauthority and .xinitrc

Comment: I disabled my NVIDIA GPU in the BIOS settings and found that startx works with just Intel, indicating that the problem is related to NVIDIA. Any ideas?

Comment: SDDM starts a session from the ones defined in `/usr/share/xsessions/`.  `startx` and `xinit` use `xinitrc`.  You're going to have to debug your `xinitrc` -- sprinkle it with `echo`s and see how far it gets.  There may be something under `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` that's causing a problem with NVIDIA.

Comment: The only files in /usr/share/xsessions/ are `bspwm.desktop` and `Plasma.desktop`. I added a .bak after the 2 files in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` and nothing changed. I just changed to bspwm so I'm updating my .xinitrc file in the post. Just before `exec bspwm` I get these messages: `Couldn't retrieve monitors via RandR.` and `Xinerama is inactive.`. I also get `/home/zjeffer/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc: line 3: bpsc: command not found`.

Comment: Another message I get is `xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted) `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

to my `~/.xinitrc` file and that made me able to boot with my NVIDIA GPU enabled in BIOS, and without SDDM.

The reason why that wasn't added yet was because when using SDDM I had to add that to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` instead of to `~/.xinitrc`. I completely forgot that I didn't add it my `~/.xinitrc` file like it says [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Display_Managers).